# $\int{({\sin{x}})^{101}\cdot \sin{99x}}\ dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

> Integrate,
>
> $$ \int{({\sin{x}})^{101}\cdot \sin({99x}})\ dx $$

I have seen this [Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381867/need-help-solving-int-sin-101x-cdot-sin99x-dx) and tried to proceed the same way but it doesn't work.

I also tried writing this as,

$$ \int{({\sin{x}})^{99}\cdot \sin({99x}}) - (\cos{x})^2 ({\sin{x}})^{99}\cdot \sin({99x}) $$

I was able to solve the first term using,

$$\sin{99x}=\sin({100x})\cos({x})-cos({100x})\sin({x})$$

But the second term is giving me problem. How should I proceed?

Comment: What do you mean by *evaluate*? That is not a number, it is an indefinite integral. Anyway, $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ and the binomial theorem are enough.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, Edited.

Comment: In case you're wondering if this has a compact representation as the one in the link of your question, I don't think it does.

Comment: I agree with @Ahmad, [depending on your definition of compact](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin(99x)*sin(x)%5E101).

Comment: @tilper hahaha it's not so compact after all !!